# Is there any way to put watch on thousand directory using one file handle

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Environment
Windows 7.0, visual studio 2010 (VC++)

Hi,
I want to put watch on thousand directory using window api FindFirstChangeNotification which is creating thousand file handles. Is there any way to put watch on thousand directory using one file handle?

Thanks in advance,
Vijay

Comment: You can put a watch on higher level directory that contain all those dir.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as Arpit says and put the watch on a higher-level directory which contains those directories.

Alternatively you can use the USN journal:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798(v=vs.85).aspx